# Running XML Parser in Android Fragment (Slide Menu) [edited]

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-fragments

I have some problem when developing Android Apps with SlideMenu. I'm going to made a fragment called "BeritaTerbaru", but I got new exception in logcat.
Here's the code :

```
public class BeritaTerbaru extends Fragment {

    // All variables
        XMLParser parser;
        Document doc;
        String xml;
        ListView lv;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        private String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/list_paging/?page=1";

        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

        // Flag for current page
        int current_page = 1;
        public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

            menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            new loadMoreListView().execute();

            // LoadMore button
            Button btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());
            btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

            // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
            lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

            // Getting adapter
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            /**
             * Listening to Load More button click event
             * */
            btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Starting a new async task
                    new loadMoreListView().execute();
                }
            });


            /**
             * Listening to listview single row selected
             * **/
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                            .getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beritaterbaru,container,false);
            return view;
        }

        /**
         * Async Task that send a request to url
         * Gets new list view data
         * Appends to list view
         * */
        private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
                        // increment current page
                        current_page += 1;

                        // Next page request
                        URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/list_paging/?page=" + current_page;

                        xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                        doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                        // looping through all item nodes <item>
                        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            menuItems.add(map);
                        }
                        return null;
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                // closing progress dialog
                pDialog.dismiss();

                // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
                int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                // Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
                 adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                                menuItems);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                // Setting new scroll position
                lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
            }
        }
}
```

here is the log cat :

```
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 895
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BeritaTerbaru$loadMoreListView.doInBackground(BeritaTerbaru.java:127)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BeritaTerbaru$loadMoreListView.doInBackground(BeritaTerbaru.java:1)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-25 00:33:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  ... 4 more
06-25 00:33:00.830: W/EGL_emulation(895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-25 00:33:01.180: W/EGL_emulation(895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-25 00:33:01.380: I/Choreographer(895): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-25 00:33:02.270: I/Choreographer(895): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b4fa1328 V.E..... R......D 0,0-383,96} that was originally added here
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BeritaTerbaru$loadMoreListView.onPreExecute(BeritaTerbaru.java:117)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BeritaTerbaru.onStart(BeritaTerbaru.java:49)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1724)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:918)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1858)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5259)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2149)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
06-25 00:33:02.940: E/WindowManager(895):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got another support class like XMLParser, ListViewAdapter, SingleListMenu, and another fragment class. But I think my mistake is in this class. Anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Inside `onStart()` remove below lines

```
    parser = new XMLParser();
    xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID)); // id not using any where
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }
```

and add

```
new loadMoreListView().execute();
```

At the same time you cannot do UI update inside `doInBackground` change your `AsyncTask` like below

```
private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
                // increment current page
                current_page += 1;

                // Next page request
                URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/list_paging/?page=" + current_page;

                parser = new XMLParser();
                xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems.add(map);
                }
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // closing progress dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
        int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        // Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
         adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                        menuItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setting new scroll position
        lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, networkonmainthread didnt show up anymore, but I still got a force close. Logcat said Fatal Exception Asynctask #1

Comment: @dmsyd can you post you full stacktrace?

Comment: @dmsyd What is line number 127 in `BeritaTerbaru.java`

Comment: @dmsyd I didn't ask xml. I asked which line is 127 in `BeritaTerbaru.java`

Comment: @dmsyd Use `parser = new XMLParser();` before `xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);`

Comment: 'xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML'

Comment: @dmsyd Use `parser = new XMLParser();` before that line